# Why aren't updates to my mongodb query NOT always reflecting?

Tags: meteor

I have a `Sessions.get()` in my MongoDB query. This means the displayed collection depends on the `Sessions.get()` value. To give you a clearer image of what I mean, find below what my query looks like:

```
 Template.paymentB2C.onCreated( function(){
  Session.set('pendingFilter', [ "Pending", "Failed", "Success" ]);
});
```

.

```
Template.paymentB2C.helpers({

    'showTransactions': function(){

        var transactions = paymentDetails.find({ 
                           paymentStatus:{$in: Session.get('Filter')} 
                           }).fetch();

        return transactions;                    
    }   

});
```

The above code displays a list of transactions. The displayed list of transactions varies in types of transactions suggesting: **Failed, Successful, to Pending transactions** as seen more accurately below:

```
0:
  payersName: "Sa Acea"
  paymentStatus: "Success"
  _id: "D3gY4BoR2tvxdK4xv"
1:
  payersName: "Paul Acea"
  paymentStatus: "Pending"
  _id: "ajCjYbLaDP7x4iAFK"
2:
  payersName: "Simon Bolton"
  paymentStatus: "Success"
  _id: "K4d6wDrjRRdSyCkhW"
```

I, therefore, use the `Filter` Session values as a **Filter** to dictate what types of transactions to display.

I am able to interchange between the three types of **Filters** via the below events. Find below the code.

```
Template.paymentB2C.events({

  'click .ShowFailedTransactions' (event, instance) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('Filter', [ "Failed" ]);
    },

  'click .ShowSuccessfulTransactions' (event, instance) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('Filter', [ "Success" ]);
    },

  'click .ShowPendingTransactions' (event, instance) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('Filter', [ "Pending" ]);
    },

});
```

**Note** that there isn't a **Failed** transaction type in the collection. So I find it very strange that whenever I choose the **Failed** filter `'click .ShowFailedTransactions'` expecting the desired effect to be a **blank empty page**, the page fails to update and continues to the show the results of the previous query, as if I never clicked `'click .ShowFailedTransactions'`.

I thought perhaps the `Session.set('Filter', [ "Failed" ])` in the `'click .ShowFailedTransactions'` function wasnt working, so I added a `console.log();` to print out the **Filter** Session **value** as seen below:

```
  'click .ShowFailedTransactions' (event, instance) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('Filter', [ "Failed" ]);
      var displaySession = Session.get('Filter');
      console.log("Filter Value is: " +displaySession );
    },
```

The above code yields `Filter Value is: Failed` in the browser console, suggesting that the **Filter** session value gets updated as expected.

I am confused, to why the page will not respond/update to this.

Kindly help suggest a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the `fetch`, it's not reactive! The good news is that you don't need it. Try this:

```js
Template.paymentB2C.helpers({
  'showTransactions': function(){
    return paymentDetails.find({paymentStatus: {$in: Session.get('Filter')}});
  }
});
```